# If the Oral Torah is Divine, why are there arguments?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, halacha-theory, oral-torah, machlokes, proof-of-torah

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don’t we just follow the shittah of Moshe Rabeinu?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18735/why-dont-we-just-follow-the-shittah-of-moshe-rabeinu)

If the Oral Torah is Divine, how are there arguments in the Mishnah and Gemara?

(I have heard this question asked several times and I wish to be equipped properly to answer it.)

Comment: Dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18735/5

Comment: @SethJ, yes, I think so. Why didn't you vote to close?

Comment: @msh210 I wanted feedback first.

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing this question as an exact duplicate of the one referenced. They obviously overlap, but this question is of a far more basic nature, whereas that question was focused on a specific detail.

Answer (score 2):

The laws could have been forgotten. 3,000 (!) halachos were lost in the time of the mourning for Mosheh ([Rashi, Yehoshua 1:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14264&st=&pgnum=6)). However, the only disputes were in matters of logic, but not in tradition ([Tosfos Yom Tov, Avos 1:4](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37946&st=&pgnum=301)).

Comment: If i would say this, they would reply: If they were forgotten then how do we know they are correct now? They are no longer necessarily Divine since these aren't the actual halachot given at Sinai

Comment: We don't know. In fact, we follow the agreement of the majority of rabbis even when there's a clear sign from G-d that the minority opinion is right (as in the case of the [tanur achnai](https://sites.google.com/site/interactivetanurshelachnai/home/the-story))

Comment: What, then, is the source for following the majority?

Comment: @AaronLevian Exodus 23:2

Comment: ba What exactly is an argument of logic? Did some Tannaim hold of [Non-Normal Logics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_modal_logic)?

Comment: @DoubleAA The Tosfos Yom Tov continues the sentence by saying it's referring to the 13 things by which the Torah is expounded

Comment: @ba So that includes the vast, vast majority of halacha! (Interesting BTW that he doesn't exclude Gezera Shava.)

Comment: How do you explain http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=3&daf=15b&format=text ?

Comment: As this pretty much a duplicate of pzkd's answer to the older question of which this question has now been closed as a duplicate, I'm not merging this answer over to the other question.