# Food brachot before and after eating

Tags: blessing, halacha-theory

Does a bracha said after eating a specific food rely on the food being eaten or on the bracha (and its intention) made at the beginning?

If, hypothetically, I make a shehakol at the beginning and then find out that the food I am eating (or "I have just finished eating") should have demanded a mezonot, would my bracha achrona be a borei nefashot (as it called forth by the intention/awareness I had when I said the bracha before eating) or an al hamichya (as it is called forth by the particular food that I ate, whether I knew it at the time or not)?

The Shehakol, bedieved, seems to have been acceptable according to the Rambam in [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/45573/1362) answer.

Comment: If you skip the initial blessing altogether, do you then skip the after blessing?

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30873/759

Comment: Not all opening blessings have a fixed after blessing. If I said בורא פרי העץ by accident, how would I know what after blessing to say?

Comment: The bracha acharona is not depending from the rishona at all

Answer (score 1):

Bracha Rishona and Bracha Acharona are two separate categories that are not connected. For example, rice is mezonos and borei nefashos at the same time.

So a mistake in one would not affect the other.