# Are there any types of questions that Eliyahu (Elijah) cannot answer?

Tags: eliyahu-hanavi

The Gemarrah often lists disputes that end in "Teiku". I understood that this term was an acronym that meant that Eliyahu will eventually answer such questions and problems. Are there any types of questions mentioned in the Gemarrah or elsewhere that Eliyahu cannot answer? (Please don't say "this one", LOL :-)

Comment: Teiku is an Aramaic word meaning "let it stand" because we let the question stand unanswered.

Comment: R' Yom Tov Lipmann Heller writes that, although *teiku* is popularly known as an acronym for תשבי יתרץ קושיות ואבעיות, it is actually a portmanteau meaning תהא קאי  (*Tosafos Yom Tov* on *Eiduyos* 8:7).

Comment: @Fred - please simplify your explanation. Many readers may not understand the Hebrew terms. I know the common acronym for "Taiku", but don't understand what you mean by תהא קאי and how this answers my question.

Comment: @DanF It wasn't meant as an answer to your question; it's just a comment on the popular acronym. Your point about Eliyahu answering questions is still valid. Anyway, תשבי יתרץ קושיות ואבעיות means "the Tishbite (Eliyahu) will answer difficulties and queries," and תהא קאי means "let it stand" (as mentioned by DoubleAA).

Comment: FYI, there are also places in gemara where it says יהי מונח עד שיבא אליהו ("let it rest until Eliyahu comes"), which is somewhat more explicit than "Teiku".

Comment: @ShimonbM Those are not cases of _s'feika d'dina_. Those are a _safek d'metziut_ such as we have no way of knowing whom this belongs to.

Comment: @DoubleAA - Where in the question does it limit responses to sfeiqa dedina? (And for the record, I don't think that issues of sfeiqa demetziut have anything to do with Eliyahu either; it's a catch-all expression, which means "one day we'll know", or "perhaps we'll never know". Like saying, "I'll tell you when the moshiach comes", which also has nothing to do with the moshiach providing the information.)

Comment: @ShimonbM I don't disagree with anything you just said. I was just pointing out that your more explicit formulation has a distinctly different context.

Comment: When Moshiach will come, i.e. the exact date and time.

Comment: @DannyF Very funny ... A paradox is not exactly an answer ;-)

Comment: the OP asked: "Are there any types of questions that Eliyahu (Elijah) cannot answer?" One of the questions is when Moshiach will come!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Eliyahu HaNavi is found along the chain of the mesorah from Moshe Rabenu and received the entire tradition (Introduction To Mishne Torah) and as such would be capable of answering any Halachic question. (At this point in history there were no disagreement among scholars - בראשונה לא הייתה מחלוקת בישראל אלא על הסמיכה בלבד‏ -ירושלמי, חגיגה פרק ב דף עז.) It is implied by Mishna Eduyos (8:7 and commentaries) that Eliyahu will answer Halachic questions at the end of days and resolve all scholarly disputes (Raavad ibid and Shoshanim LeDovid (Fardo)).

For non-Halachic matters, we find that no Navi (Eliyahu included) truly understood the nature of the reward in Olam Habah - only G-d knows it (Sandehrin 99a):

> אמר רבי חייא בר אבא א"ר יוחנן כל הנביאים כולן לא נתנבאו אלא לימות
>   המשיח אבל לעולם הבא (ישעיהו סד, ג) עין לא ראתה א---ם זולתך יעשה למחכה
>   לו

We now discuss some cases where Eliyahu HaNavi either would not be followed *if* he would issue a ruling on a matter or he would not act on some matter.

It is tacitly implied that Eliyahu's authority is generally binding in Halacha since the Talmud writes that his opinion is followed except where it contradicts accepted Halachic practice

ר' בא רב יהודה בשם רב אם יבא אליהו ויאמר שחולצין
 במנעל שומעין שלו.  שאין חולצין בסנדל אין שומעין לו.  שהרי הרבים נהגו לחלוץ בסנדל

(Bavli Menacos 32a, Yerushami, Yevamos 12,1)

The Mishna (Eduyos ח,ז) writes that Eliyahu will not not distance families that have already been accepted into the Jewish community. The Mishna does not say that he does not personally know those families. rather, he won't act on that knowledge.

אמר רבי יהושוע, מקובל אני מרבן יוחנן בן זכאי ששמע מרבו ורבו מרבו, הלכה למשה 
מסיניי, שאין אלייהו בא לטמא ולטהר, לרחק ולקרב, אלא לרחק את המקורבין בזרוע, ולקרב 
את המרוחקין בזרוע.

A common misconception is that תיקו literally means "תשבי יתרץ קושיות ובעיות" - Eliyahu Ha'Navi will answer questions and queries. That is not correct. It literally means the question will stand unanswered. "תשבי יתרץ קושיות ובעיות" is a [derush](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95) and is found in early sources ( Shla Torah She bal Peh, Tosfis Yom Tov Eduyos ibid)

For a discussion as to whether Eliyahu's authority is based on *Nevuah* or *Chachmah* see [Sdei Chemed Ma'arechet Mem, Klal Lamed Chet](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14145&pgnum=85), sh"ut Chsssam Sofer 6:98 and introduction to Sh"ut Min Hashamayim R Margolios edition

For an extensive discussion on this and related issues see Encyclopedia Talmudit entry on Eliyahu.

Comment: Isn't Rav Ashi in that same chain? He had doubts and questions...

Comment: @Yoni - This is great! You must be a rebbe to locate and summarize such a thorough answer. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't go so far as calling it "a common misconception." The Mabit ([*Sha'ar HaY'sdos* §60](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14113&st=&pgnum=285)) mentioned it as an acronym for תשבי יתרץ קושיות והויות, though he likely meant this only *derech remez*.

Comment: ...Also, the Mabit indicates that Eliyahu's exceptional knowledge includes esoteric matters of "the upper world": הוא מוכן לדעת כל הדברים העליונים המתחדשים בעולם העליון, מצד דקות נפשו, וידיעת כל הדברים ההוים בעוה"ז מצד זכות גופו. Anyway, nice answer +1.

Comment: @Fred Agreed. I only said that there is a misconception that this is the *literal* meaning of Teku.

Comment: @Yoni Ah, yes. I may have skimmed your answer a bit too quickly. Good on you.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18735/759

Comment: can you point out where in Shem HaGedolim the Chida discusses Eliyahu Hanavi? http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/tohen.asp?id=306

Answer (score 1):

The Kedushah says the angels ask each other, "Where is the place of HaShem's glory?" and do not answer, since there are limits to what anyone can understand about HaShem - even angels and even Eliyahu.

Thus, while Eliyahu might be able to answer any *halachic* questions, there are some theological/philosophical questions which only HaShem can answer and understand.

Comment: While I think your answer is fundamentally correct, it would benefit from more thorough sourcing. +1.

Comment: While the text of the question focused mainly on the Gemarrah, as the term "Taiku" is there, I am curious about other types of questions outside the Gemarrah. Explaining the "Taiku" - Do I correctly infer that such questins can NOT be answered by Eliyahu if you say it means "Let it stand"> Does that mean "forever" or "just for now"?

Answer (score 0):

Rav Elchonon Waserman seems to have assumed that Eliyahu Hanavi had the same power as any other eid echad could theoretically have, not more. Therefore, in cases of isur v'heter where an eid echad is relied upon, we could rely on him. We wouldn't rely on him alone, however, to sentence a person to death, because there is a gzeiras hakasuv against this. Also, by dinei mamonus (monetary laws), where two eidim are required, it seems that R' Elchonon held we would not rely on him. The following is R' Elchonon's lashon in קובץ שעורים קונטרס דברי סופרים סימן ה
אות ג, ד

Os ג is just for context. Os ד is where he lays out his main point for our purposes.

> ג) הקושיא הב' תירצו דגבי דיינים
> המיעוט כמי שאינו וגם טענת מוחזק ליכא דב"ד מפקי מיניה וא"כ אין שם לא
> מיעוט ולא מוחזק וכונתם במ"ש דגבי דיינים המיעוט כמי שאינו נראה לפי
> המבואר בס"פ הזהב בתנורו של עכנאי דיצתה ב"ק ואמרה הלכה כר"א ולא השגיחו
> חכמים על דבריה דכבר כתוב בתורה אחרי רבים להטות ומבואר מזה דהא דיחיד
> ורבים הלכה כרבים הוא אפילו אם ידוע לנו בבירור ברוה"ק שהאמת הוא כדברי
> היחיד ואילו בט' חניות מוכרות בשר שחוטה ואחת מוכרת בשר נבילה דבנמצא הלך
> אחרי הרוב אם נדע ע"פ נביא שהחתיכה היא מהמיעוט ודאי לא נלך אחר הרוב
> מפני שהרוב אינו מהפך את האיסור להיתר אלא שמברר שהדבר הוא מהרוב אבל
> במקום שנביא מוחזק אומר שהדבר הוא מהמיעוט בכה"ג הרוב לא מעלה ולא מוריד.
>
> ד) ואף שכתב הרמב"ם בפירוש המשנה בסנהדרין פ' נגמר הדין ז"ל ודע שהריגת יהושע לעכן היתה הוראת שעה לפי שתורתינו האמיתית אינה מחייבת מיתה על
> החוטא בהודאתו בעצמו ולא בנבואת נביא שיאמר שעשה זה המעשה עכ"ל אבל זהו
> רק במקום שצריך שני עדים כשרים דגזה"כ הוא על פי שני עדים יקום דבר
> ואפילו משה ואהרן לא מהימני במקום שצריך שני עדים דאף שהדבר אמת אין
> לעשות אלא בעדות כשר כמ"ש תוס' גיטין ד"ד עיין שם אבל באיסורין דע"א וכל
> הפסולין נאמנים בודאי סומכין על הנביא וד"ז מפורש להדיא בפסחים די"ג
> דקאמר שם האיך נשרוף את התלויה עם הטמאה שמא יבא אליהו ויטהרנה אמרו לו
> כבר מובטח להן לישראל שאין אליהו בא לא בערבי שבתות ולא בערבי ימים טובים
> ע"כ ומבואר להדיא שסומכין על אליהו באיסורין וכן נראה מלשון המשנה פ'
> המפקיד יהא מונח עד שיבא אליהו ואף דאיירי בדיני ממון אבל התם ע"א נאמן
> לברר כיון דשניהן מוחזקין בשוה וע"כ נסמוך גם על אליהו ובתוס' פ"ק דחולין
> ד"ה עפ"י הדבור שאני גבי אליהו שהעורבים הביאו לו בשר ולא נאסר משום בשר
> שנתעלם מן העין דידע עפ"י הדבור שהוא בשר כשר עיין שם.