# Source that "Teiku" References Eliyahu?

Tags: sources-mekorot, words, etymology, eliyahu-hanavi

What is the earliest source that indicates that "teiku" (תיקו) references Eliyahu?
Any source earlier than the Tosafos Yom Tov who provides an alternative explanation?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2024/759

Comment: Also related: Comments and answer (and comments on answer) on http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38127.

Comment: See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/38132/5247

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The earliest source<sup>1</sup> seems to be from the [ספר הפליאה - ספר הקנה](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%94) who [writes](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%90%D7%94_-_%D7%93%22%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8_%D7%9C%D7%95_%D7%90%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95_%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%95):

> ויש פירושים רבים שנעלמו מעיני כל חי ועתיד אליהו הנביא לפרשם וזהו מה שרמזו רז"ל בשבעה מסכתות תיקו "תשבי "יתרץ "קושיות "ובעיות.

<sup>1</sup>Before 1390, according to linked Wikipedia article

Comment: were you assuming that it was written in the 15th century? or earlier?

Comment: Zvi, I linked a wikipedia page and added an estimated date accordingly. If you prefer a different source, feel free to [edit]. +1

Comment: @Yez the date of authorship is unknown some think that it was authored largely or partly in the 15th century. see [here](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%90%D7%94).

Comment: @mevaqesh assuming this particular part was of the later, still precedes Tishbi by at least a century.

Comment: @YeZ if we knew it was written by r. arvigdor kra that would would put it only a few decades before Tishbi whose author was born 30 years after the the former's death. However, given that we dont know who authored or finished adding to the Pliah, Tishbi is the earliest **confirmed** source.

Comment: @mevaqesh Tishbi was not actually written immediately after the author was born.  It was written much later in his life. And Pliah may be disputed, but the _latest_ opinions put it in early 15th.  As early as 13th. I don't know why you need a confirmed exact year to be a valid source - it is certainly earlier than Tishbi.

Answer (score 5):

Another source earlier than the Tosafos Yom Tov is the work Tishbi by R. Eliya Habachur of the 15th-16th century who disputes the idea [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37938&hilite=53f451d8-acac-4324-96b6-e9eccbba92a3&st).

Comment: Thats a pretty harsh commentless downvote of a legitimate answer to the question (even of not the best answer) as it is earlier than the Tosafos Yom Tov