# How exactly would Eliyahu resolve monetary disputes? (ie "מֻנָּח עַד שֶׁיָּבֹא אֵלִיָּהוּ")

Tags: eliyahu-hanavi, bava-metzia

In the beginning *perakim* of Bava Metzia, there are several *mishnayos* (see: [1:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Bava_Metzia.1.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [2:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Bava_Metzia.2.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [3:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Bava_Metzia.3.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [3:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Bava_Metzia.3.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) that present cases when there is uncertainty as to who the owner of an item may be, and state:

> יְהֵא מֻנָּח עַד שֶׁיָּבֹא אֵלִיָּהוּ
> it should remain [ie set aside] until Eliyahu comes

#### Question

I understand how Eliyahu could explain Torah stalemates (ie if [תיקו](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53709/source-that-teiku-references-eliyahu) is an acronym etc) as Eliyahu can reveal and resolve complex halachik questions.

But I assume Eliyahu wouldn't have a crystal ball etc- so **how would Eliyahu be able to determine the rightful owner of an object or a monetary case between 2 people?**

Comment: See [Eduyot 8:7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Eduyot.8.7?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) for the dispute about what Eliyahu will do when he comes

Comment: I would that the opposite of your assumption is true - halachic principles are *determined* by majority vote of the Sanhedrin in which a prophet has no special standing (*lo bashamayim hi*); questions of historical reality, however (such as who lost an object), should be resolvable by prophecy, upon its return.

Comment: @Loewian Question assumes the Eliyahu doesn't have a "crystal ball". Not sure why he makes that assumption, being a *navi* and all...

Comment: Further, as per Samuel I 9, it seems reuniting lost objects with their owners was very much under the purview of the prophets.

Comment: @Loewian right but how so? Nevuah or some other method etc?

Comment: I would assume so. Otherwise, why would you need a navi?

Comment: @Loewian I hear- it's just hard me to grasp that when we finally have a Navi and everything that's he's capable of doing (ie Torah, halacha, etc)... that we'll use him to see who the rightful owner of $20 is.

Comment: That's why I referenced the story with Saul.