# Story identification: Rabbeinu Tam argues with Moshe Rabbeinu

Tags: sources-mekorot, tefilin, story-identification

In [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18748/17563), a strange and rather fascinating story is quoted from the Seder Hadoros:

> *Seder Hadoros (year 4930) brings the story of an argument between
>   Rabeynu Tam and other Rishonim regarding how one should tie the knot
>   of the Tefillin. Eventually, Moshe Rabeynu himself is called down from
>   heaven and asked his opinion. He testifies that he personally saw the
>   back of Hashem's Tefillin shel Rosh, but Rabeynu Tam is not persuaded.
>   In the words of the Seder Hadoros: "Rabeynu Tam got up like a lion and
>   said Moshe Rabeynu you are mistaken!".*

Does anyone have a source for this story, and/or any record of discussion regarding the veracity and validity of this story?

Comment: I'm sure you saw the comment on that answer citing sources that this story is apikorsus.

Comment: [Seder Haddorot](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46817&pgnum=231) quotes מ' הג"מ עזריאל טרביטו ספר גדול קשור בו סודות ועניני קבלה. I couldn't find any information on him. Also, [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18740/1569) might have been an inspiration for the story.

Comment: "In Nefesh Harav pg 45-46, R. Hershel Schachter writes that he heard from R. Soloveitchik in the name of R. Chaim that the first story that you bring from the Seder Hadoros is apikorsus" - Comment from הנער הזה on linked question

Comment: Story is much more exciting in the original than quoted in the linked answer...

Comment: Since the knot of the tefillin shel rosh is 'Halacha l'Moshe mi'Sinai', it's difficult to imagine that Rabbeinu Tam would have said such a thing. See Ritva to Eruvin 97a:2 and Menachot 35b said in the name of Rav.

Comment: If memory serves, the argument centered on whether the kesher of the tefillin Shel Yad needs to be recreated every day or not. The knot of the Shel Rosh isn't germane...

Comment: https://daf-yomi.com/DYItemDetails.aspx?itemId=22396

Answer (score -1):

You can read this in [Seder HaDorot, volume i, page 208](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46817&st=&pgnum=231), from R' Yechiel Heilprin. The link is to HebrewBooks.org, but you can also read a transcription of the story [here](https://daf-yomi.com/DYItemDetails.aspx?itemId=22396).

Heilprin begins by writing :

[image: source for story]

So, if I understand correctly, he saw this in a sefer in the library of R' Aziel Tarbito, and the version came from the midrash of R' Shmuel b'R' Eliyahu of Ibra (??)ץ