# Can one rely on Rabeinu Tam's shkia for Rabeinu Tam's Tefillin?

Tags: halacha, tefilin, zemanim, rabbeinu-tam

If its past normal shkia, yet before Rabeinu Tam's shkia, can one still put on Rabeinu Tam's Tefillin, even though Tefillin isn't supposed to be put on at night in general, since one is anyways relying on the opinion of Rabeinu Tam for the sake of the Tefillin itself?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Yankileh and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: cf. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12772/170

Comment: @msh210 interesting place to begin the investigation

Comment: Rabbenu Tam was just ruling like Rav Hai Gaon for what we call "Rabbenu Tam Tefillin" so really you're relying on him, and "traditionally" Rav Hai Gaon holds of "normal" shkiya. (I'm ignoring that despite "common knowledge" most likely none of those people held any of those things.) In general these arguments never work unless the two positions are conceptually linked, which these are clearly not.

Comment: https://www.mosdot-ariel.org/%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%AA-%D7%91%D7%96%D7%9E%D7%9F-%D7%A8%D7%AA/ where he basically says if you hold RT tefillin is a sfeika dedina (which is few people nowadays) then even at vadai night you should be allowed to put them on in private with a shomer to keep you from sleeping since that need is at least as great as the need to guard tefillin from damage. But the argument in this question is definitely insufficient.

Comment: None of this addresses the fact that kosher tefillin can plausibly be donned during bein hashemashot so "sunset" isn't even the relevant cut-off time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per [Machon Aliya](https://www.aliya.org.il/11-%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%91%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A9%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%AA-%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%95-%D7%AA%D7%9D/) Rabbi Chaim Pinchas Scheinberg Zatzal would put on Tefilin Rabbeinu Tam between Shekiya and the Zeman of Rabbeinu Tam.

> הגרח"פ שיינברג זצ"ל שנהג להניח תפילין במשך כל היום, היה מניח תפילין
> דרבינו תם מזמן השקיעה עד זמן רבינו תם

Per [Olamot.Net](https://olamot.net/shiur/%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%A9%D7%9C-%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%95-%D7%AA%D7%9D) Rabbi Yechezkel Sarna Zatzal would put on Tefilin of Rabbeinu Tam after Shekiya.

> והגר"י סרנא, ראש ישיבת חברון, הניח בסוף ימיו תפילין של ר"ת דווקא אחר
> השקיעה

Comment: Who is Machon Aliya? Everyone please be very skeptical of this practice

Comment: @DoubleAa https://www.aliya.org.il/about/our-team/