# Why does a Torah have 2 poles and a Megillah have 1?

Tags: halacha, megillat-esther, sefer-torah, safrus

A Torah scroll is a very long piece of parchement with two poles ("atzei chayim") at either end, while a Megillat Esther is a not-as-long piece of parchment with one pole at the end of the book.

[image: http://bit.ly/KUSLRO] [image: http://bit.ly/KBHw20]

Why the difference? Two poles seems the most convienient, as it allows you to save your place when you close it. Why not do that for the Megillah as well?

Comment: This may have something to do with the Megillah being a "letter".

Comment: @HodofHod A source that suggests that would be most interesting!

Comment: Well, it's the reason why Chabad doesn't use any polls at all....

Comment: @HodofHod Given the sources in msh210's answer, either that is much older than Chabad or it is a post facto justification.

Comment: Oh, I didn't suggest that Chabad is the originator, only that the reason I've always heard for why there's no poll, and that it's folded while read, is that it's a letter. Could be post facto or not, I'm not sure what the source for the reason is.

Comment: It doesn't give a reason, but the source is the Talmud, Baba Batra 14A - http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=23&daf=14&format=pdf

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40351&st=&pgnum=35

Comment: http://www.or-lasofer.com/Article1.asp?ArticleRowID=560

Comment: related? [What is the roll of a Navi?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55591/759)

Answer (score 6):

(Note that not every *m'gila* has a pole at one end. Some do, though, as you note. See [*Mishna B'rura* 691:16](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14166&pgnum=316).)

[*Aruch Hashulchan* (*Orach Chayim* 691:7)](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%A6%D7%90#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.AA.D7.A8.D7.A6.D7.90_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.96) explains:

> A *sefer Tora* (Torah scroll) requires two poles because we read from it constantly; for *n'viim* and *k'suvim* one pole suffices.

I suspect the intent is that a *sefer Tora* needs the greater stability that the poles provide because it's used so often; see also the comments on this answer. (*AHS* notes further (there) that one possible reason for a *m'gila* to have no pole at all (rather than one) is that it's used so very infrequently.)

Comment: +1 I wonder though if you look at the earlier sources if you'll find a more concrete and explicit distinction. Right now it's still a little speculative extrapolation on your part.

Comment: Not that I see as of yet.

Comment: As a more practical manner the m'gila is unrolled in its entirety when it is read. This is easier with one or no poles.

Comment: I suspect that the Aruch HaShulchan is saying that because it is used constantly, it would be a pain to have to roll it all the way up every time you stepped away from it, which is something you'd have to do if it only had one pole. If it has two poles, you can close it while still maintaining your place.

Comment: plus, there is a lot more to roll in a sefer torah

Comment: @Menachem, yeah, could very well be.

Comment: @Menachem, and we read a _m'gila_ in its entirety every time we read it.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that Torah scrolls didn't always have 2 poles but that it was added for greater maneuverability. See this [Hakirah article](http://www.hakirah.org/Vol%205%20Epstein.pdf) (p.210 - 211) for some speculation on when and why this change was made.

Answer (score 0):

Haran suggests the bars were adopted from Rome. The second bar was added to avoid having to unwind and rewind the scroll at every use, and was used in Rome by at least the first century CE.

Based on literary sources, Haran argues that a single bars was used for all scrolls until near the end of the Talmudic era, when double bars became standard. There is no recorded reason for the change and it is likely that it was done for pragmatic reasons.

See "Torah and Bible Scrolls in the First Centuries of the Christian Era", Shnaton 10:100-101. (In Hebrew.)

[image: Torah and Bible Scrolls in the First Centuries of the Christian Era]

Comment: Wait, so you mean that when they got towards Vezot Haberacha they would spend 10 minutes beforehand unrolling and 10 minutes afterwards rerolling, every Monday and Thursday and twice on Shabbos?  That's very inconvenient.

Comment: @Heshy It is not clear how they were rolled. It is possible that it could have been rolled without a bar. I am also not sure if there always was a tradition to have the entire torah in a single scroll.

Comment: Which bar does Haran suggest was first and which was added later?

Comment: @DoubleAA I am unable to find him saying which one explicitly. As one may expect, the literary sources are largely silent about this. Ostensibly, it was the left one. Take a look at the facsimile of page 101 I posted.