# What is the role of a Navi?

Tags: sources-mekorot, navi-prophets

Are there sources discussing what the role of a navi (prophet) is in Judaism?

For example, is he/she a historian, a bearer of God's word, a bringer to repent?

Obviously different prophets do different jobs, but I'm looking for sources that bring a theory about the general role of a navi

Comment: http://www.jewfaq.org/prophet.htm

Answer (score 3):

The Rambam discusses this at length in the [introduction to his commentary on the Mishnah](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37939&st=&pgnum=44):

> ודע, שהנבואה לא תועיל בעיון בפירושי התורה ולמידת הדינים בי"ג מדות, אלא
> מה שיעשה יהושע ופינחס בעניני העיון והדין הוא מה שיעשה רבינא ורב אשי.
> אבל לשאלת מה הוא יתרון הנביא ופעולתו במצות הרי הוא חי נפשי מן היסודות
> הגדולים והעצומים שעליהם משען הדת ויסודו.
>
> ונראה לי שכאן ראוי לי לבאר את
> היסוד הזה...והחלק השני, שיקרא לעבודת ה' ויזהיר על תורתו, ויצוה בני אדם
> על שמירת התורה בלי תוספת ולא גרעון, כמו שאמר אחרון הנביאים זכרו תורת
> משה עבדי אשר צויתי אותו בחורב על כל ישראל חקים ומשפטים. ויבטיח טובות
> לשומריה ועונש לעוברים עליה כמו שעשו ישעיה וירמיה ויחזקאל וזולתם. ויצוה
> צווים ויזהיר אזהרות שלא בעניני הדת, כגון שיאמר הלחמו על עיר פלונית או
> אומה פלונית עכשיו, כמו שצוה שמואל את שאול להלחם בעמלק אז. או שיזהיר
> מלהרוג כמו שהזהיר אלישע את יהורם שלא להרוג חיל חזאל הנמצאים בשומרון
> כידוע. וכמו שהזהיר ישעיה מלהכניס את המים לפנים מן החומה. וכמו שהזהיר
> ירמיה את ישראל מלצאת מירושלים, וכל כיוצא בזה.
>
> …that he will call to the service of God, and warn about violating His Torah, and command people about keeping the Torah without addition or subtraction… and assure good things to those who keep it and punishment to those who violate it… and give orders and prohibitions about non-religious matters, such as saying "battle such-and-such city or such-and-such nation now"… or warn against killing so-and-so in battle…

Answer (score 2):

to communicate messages between God and Israel as written (deut.18:18)

> I will raise them up a Prophet from among their brethren, like to you,
>   and will put my words in his mouth; and he shall speak to them all
>   that I shall command him.

Answer (score 0):

Some roles that Navi tend to take:

- mouthpiece of God
- harbinger of hope
- harbinger of doom (Ezekiel, Jeremiah)
- rally the people to repentance (Ezekiel, Jeremiah)
- leaders of the people (Moses, Shoftim)

Comment: Read the question again: Are there _sources_ discussing what the role of a navi (prophet) is in Judaism?

Answer (score -1):

see overview to Artscroll Yehoshua for an at length english description of a Navi

Comment: If you don't have access to this please let me know.

Comment: What does it say? Always good to summarize the content of the source on Mi.Yodeya

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya M.C.S. answers must provide the answers themselves; not just sources for them. If you want, a moderator can convert this answer into a comment. || If you want another user to be pinged on a comment of yours, put a @ in front of his username in the comment. e.g. @mevaqesh

Comment: The question asks for sources, not necessarily answers. This answer provides a source, as requested.